# getting notification when contactslist changed

Tags: android

I'm working on a program that needs to get a notification about my contactslist.
I know about the ContentObserver. the issue is that I need the observer to work even when my app isn't running in front or background.

Any suggestions will be appreciated,

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a service, and have the ContentObserver run in the service.

In fact, that's the general answer for "I need to do X when not running"-  do it in a service.